# Changing cell's value via VBA doesn't launch the macro linked to the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have some add-in on my workbook I use to get some data. There is a row with info I need in different cells.

If I change manually the value of the cell of the date (for example), it will launched the macro (which i don't know the name)

But if via a sub I change the value with :

```
wsParam.Range("D5").FormulaR1C1 = date_de_recup
```

the macro won't launch.

What could i do ?

**EDIT :**

`date_de_recup` is defined like this :

`If Weekday(Date) > 2 And Weekday(Date) < 7 Then
        date_de_recup = Date - 1
Else
        date_de_recup = Date - 3
End If`

Comment: What is inside of date_de_recup?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so difficult to tell because we really don't have enough info, but perhaps this will work:

```
With wsParam.Range("D5")    
    .FormulaR1C1 = date_de_recup
    .Select
End With
```

It won't work if you fire off the macro with `D5` selected on the worksheet, and it also won't if you have `Application.EnableEvents = False`